# Create an image size with B&W image in Wordpress on regenerate thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress, image

Looking for a way to regenerate all my featured images and that it will create a new image size in B&W,

I know this can be done in CSS but I need to pull this image with REST to a JS canvas application and cannot use CSS,

I found this code but it does not seem to work in my case, 
It works on some pages with I upload images but not when I upload the image to a post, also I was wondering if there is a way to do this with Regenerate of all the thumbnails on site and not on upload.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme','themename_bw_size');
function themename_bw_size() {
    add_image_size('themename-bw-image', 100, 100, true);
}

add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','themename_bw_filter');
function themename_bw_filter($meta) {
    $file = wp_upload_dir();
    $file = trailingslashit($file['path']).$meta['sizes']['themename-bw-image']['file'];
    list($orig_w, $orig_h, $orig_type) = @getimagesize($file);
    $image = wp_load_image($file);
    imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    switch ($orig_type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            imagegif( $image, $file );
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            imagepng( $image, $file );
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            imagejpeg( $image, $file );
            break;
    }
    return $meta;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Alon, welcome to SO. What exactly *does not seem to work*?

Comment: Where have you added this code? Also, is there are reason you're using calling `add_image_size` is the `after_setup_theme` action?

Comment: The code does create a new image size, what I'm looking for is to get the code to create the new B&W image size with the greyscale filter when regenerating the thumbnails. I have more then 600 images on site I would like to create a B&W image from,